# Error R6034 in MSACCESS.EXE followed by Run-time error '-2147023782 (8007045a)'

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ms-access-2010, windows-7-x64, sqldmo

I have these error messages when I start `MS-Access` application (has `VBA` code).

When I click OK in the first error message and debug in the second, the debugger opens up and points to the line that says: "`Set oServer = New SQLDMO.SQLServer`"

I realise that it's a problem with SQL-DMO, but can't seem to register the DLL.

My environment: `Win7 Pro 64-bit`, `Office 2010 64-bit`, `MS SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2 64-bit`.

I downloaded the **backwards compatibility package** from Microsoft, ran the `MSI`, and nothing.
Tried to manually install, and get error messages:

1. `R6034` for `C:\Windows\System32\regsvr32.exe` and when I click Ok --> The module "`SQLDMO.DLL`" failed to load. `Make sure the binary is stored at the specified path or debug it`... blah blah
2. When I try to register it from `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`, I get "`The module "SQLDMO.DLL" may not (be) compatible with the version of Windows that you're running. Check if the module is compatible with....`

I've checked the version of `SQLDMO.DLL` and it is definitely 64-bit. I have located all the other DLLs that SQL-DMO needs and stored them in `SysWOW64` and `System32`.

I have run `Office repair`, `Windows Update`, `SQL Server repair` (the log file indicates pass for everything for Client Tools Backwards Compatibility).

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks, Miki.

Comment: Ok, managed to register SQLDMO.DLL by running regsvr32.exe sqldmo.dll from c:\Windows\SysWOW64. The SQLDMO.DLL is 64-bit, and from my understanding, regsvr32.exe in SysWOW64 is 32-bit, so am not sure how it registered it...

Error message still persists. Not sure what to do from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how I've managed to, but have (somehow) managed to register the 64-bit SQLDMO.DLL (before it didn't really register it) and then in my VBA code--> Tools --> References... I tried to load the SQLDMO.DLL from the 64-bit folder.
At first, it didn't work, and then I placed a copy of the DLL in SysWOW64 (which is a 32-bit folder) and registered it from there (once it was registered, apparently, the system doesn't need it there anymore - I removed it, and it still works).
I then tried to figure how come it works. I checked in the Reference Table in the VBA Code, and the Microsoft SQLDMO Object Library is still pointing to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\80\Tools\Binn, but when I removed SQLDMO.DLL from there it still worked... I then looked in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\80\Tools\Binn and removed SQLDMO.DLL from there and then it stopped working!
I have no idea what happened, or why the reference table is saying it's pointing to one folder but actually pointing to a different one, or how after the same tries before, only now it works.
I'd like to be able to replicate this (in case I need to go through this process again), so any ideas/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks, Miki.